# How to Add a blank row to asp repeater during ItemDataBound event?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I bind the repeater with SqlDataReader but I want when repater has no row than a blank row is added in ItedDataBound Event

Comment: You will have to put your code first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1- First Create A DataTable Object to hold your data

2- Check for the Number of Rows in the DataTable if Zero then Add Empty DataRow Object To DataTable

3- Bind Your Repeater to the DataTable Instead to Datareader Object

```
if(dt.Rows.Count==0)
{
DataRow dr=dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

rptDemo.DataSource=dt;
rptDemo.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Place label in the footer of repeater in FooterTemplate and by default set visible to false and in ItemDataBound set to visible=true when item count is 0 or less than 1.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDemo" runat="server"
OnItemDataBound="rptDemo_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    .......
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    <%-- Label used for no data available --%>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" CssClass="errMsg" Text="Sorry, no item is there to show." Visible="false">
    </asp:Label>
</FooterTemplate>
```

```
  protected void rptDemo_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rptDemo.Items.Count < 1)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
            {
                Label lblFooter = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblMsg");
                lblFooter.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was to show add row inside repeater. Me included a blank row as the last item by doing a small checking, in all other rows, blank row made hidden.

Used

```
<%# (((IList)((Repeater)Container.Parent).DataSource).Count).ToString() == (Container.ItemIndex + 1).ToString() %>
```

checking to decide whether to show or hide blank row.

Full code of view:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" OnItemCommand="repeater_user_Itemcommand" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    Email
                </td>
                <td>
                    Delete
                </td>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                        CommandName="delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server" visible='<%# (((IList)((Repeater)Container.Parent).DataSource).Count).ToString() == (Container.ItemIndex + 1).ToString() %>'>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName_add" runat="server" Enabled="True" Text='' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail_add" runat="server" Text='' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowAdd" runat="server" CommandName="add">Add</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```